# How do I create an IP Grabber where the user's IP only appears ONCE?

Tags: javascript, php, authentication

```
<?php
    $ip = getenv('REMOTE_ADDR');
    $port = getenv('REMOTE_PORT');
    $agent = getenv('HTTP_USER_AGENT');
    $data =  date("Y-m-d");

    $fp = fopen('IP.php', 'a');

    fwrite($fp, "\r\n");
    fwrite($fp,"<tr>");
    fwrite($fp, "\r\n");
    fwrite($fp, "<th>$ip</th>");
    fwrite($fp, "\r\n");
    fwrite($fp, "<th>$port</th>");
    fwrite($fp, "\r\n");
    fwrite($fp, "<th>$agent</th>");
    fwrite($fp, "\r\n");
    fwrite($fp, "<th>$data</th>");
    fwrite($fp, "<tr>");

    fclose($fp); 
?>
```

This IP Grabber. I need to know the INFO of the users of my site when they enter. However, I want that if the user login more than once, his IP will appear only once, if it is identical, while if it is different it must appear in the IP table.

EXAMPLE:

If within 1 time, and then within the next day with the same IP, I do not get his logs, since there are so many users I would not want it to fill up every time a user enters maybe more than once a day.

Comment: You should use a database instead of a regular file. It is much easier to handle restrictions (e.g. one log per day per user) and also a lot faster.

Comment: If this were a hobby project, I would just tell you to get the file's content, look for the IP in it, and act accordingly. But then you said `since there are so many users`. Then, the right way is to use a database. You can set a UNIQUE constraint on that field so that you don't have to handle it yourself

Comment: To clarify... Can it be done by using what appears to be a PHP source code file as storage? Absolutely. But that's the typical thing you only do as challenge, to prove it can be done.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to store logs on files(per day) without any process on written files, it could be logical, but if you want to read and process log files before new write, **You will get into trouble** with increasing read and write requests.

**So** I suggest you using a log Table in a **Database** instead of files. then make a query to find **distinct** ip values and more advanced reports.in this way you could log all user logins and other custom logs and then decide what to do with these data.

If you are **worried about increasing the size** of this table, you can put **Cron Job** on the server to **delete** old logs(with a query) nightly or weekly.

good luck